# Constraints for UIcollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, swift2

In ViewController I insert CollectionView using this code:

```
HomeMenuView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

I want to use constraints with visual format to frame the CollectionView between two objects( Top Image, bottom: button).

PS: Without using storyboard, code only.

Answer (score 1):

take look at this awesome pod to build dynamic and beautiful user interfaces like a boss, with Swift - [NEON](https://github.com/mamaral/Neon)

there, you can just add

```
yourView.alignBetweenVertical(align: .AboveCentered, primaryView: yourTopView, secondaryView: yourBottomView, padding: padding, width: size)
```

or any other code snippets from the link I provided. All constraints with one line of a code.

P.S. I wouldn't name your object instances with Capital Letter, it is not a class name, so instead of `HomeMenuView` - call it `homeMenuView`, look at code convention - [RayWanderlichCodeConvention](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your ImageView are added and properly setup with the needed constraints, also your button,

```
self.addSubview(HomeMenuView);
self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[HomeMenuView]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["HomeMenuView":HomeMenuView,"imageView":self.yourImageView,"button":self.yourButton]));
self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[imageView]-0-[HomeMenuView]-0-[button]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["HomeMenuView":HomeMenuView,"imageView":self.yourImageView,"button":self.yourButton]));
```

I also suggest you check this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html

I hope this helps

Comment: How do I call : collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()?

It will work this way: 
        HomeMenuView.collectionViewLayout = UIcollectionViewFlowLayout()

Comment: @IlieJeleazcov Sorry I don't understand your question, can you explain what you need now?

Comment: For: HomeMenuView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()), I give frame and collectionViewLayout. 

Using your method, after constraints what I'm doing with collectionViewLayout, how to declare? It will work this way: HomeMenuView.collectionViewLayout = UIcollectionViewFlowLayout() ? Or witch code I should do?

Comment: @IlieJeleazcov Just put my code just below yours, should work

Comment: Yes, it helped me. I had just to do this: HomeMenuView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()) After this I could insert the collectionView with constraints

Comment: @IlieJeleazcov ok, Im glad to hear that